# Can I easily add a search icon in a NSComboBox?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to display a search icon as placeholder in a NSComboBox exactly like in a search box:

[image]

Can this be easily done by subclassing the NSComboBox?

Comment: Why do you need NSCombobox for these purposes? Is NSTextField not enough?

Comment: @Astoria What are the purposes you are talking about?

Comment: Which functionalities of NSCombobox do you need there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you subclass NSView with NSTextField and NSImageView inside. Like a

```
NSView
 |
 |-NSImageView
 |
 |-NSComboBox
```

This class will be a `NSTextFieldDelegate`-responder:

```
- (void)controlTextDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  // change lens image view position (for example with layout constraint constant change animated)
  // change text field horizontal text alignment to Left
}

- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  // change text field horizontal text alignment to center
  // change lens image view position to default
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, and what about the functionalities of the NSComboBox?

Comment: @Patrick not a problem, you may use NSCombobox (is a NSTextField-subclass actually) too.